# VisualVM - Unable to sampler CPU/Memory

Tags: java, linux, centos, visualvm

I am unable to use the sampler on VisualVM. I am however able to see the overview & monitor remotely. Here's my startup script to the java application & a video that displays the issue I am experiencing. using CentOS.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w4jqH4x1Rzg

Startup script

```
screen -d -m -S SG java -server -Xmx8G -Xms1G -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=30 -XX:+UseBiasedLocking -XX:+OptimizeStringConcat -XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods -XX:+AggressiveOpts -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8766 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -jar spigot.jar
```

Error message

```
CPU sampling:
Not available. Cannot access threads in target application. Check the logfile for details (use Help | About | Logfile).

Memory sampling:
Not available. Failed to read objects in target application. Check the logfile for details (use Help | About | Logfile).
```

Comment: Are you sure the version of Java is the same for your application and the VisualVM?

Comment: If you can use flight recorder you might find it is better.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I am using Java 1.8.0_77 on the dedicated server & 1.8.0_74 on my computer. Does it have to have the same version number? And thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Alright so I found out the issue. I logged in as monitorRole instead of controlRole.

Answer (score 1):

The issue were that I logged in as monitorRole instead of controlRole when connecting remotely.